# How to hide status bar (react native/iOS)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Just starting out learning React Native. Going through examples on the official site. I did the Hello World example and the status bar is overlapping the text. How can I hide the status bar?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Thanks

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: Above not worked for me. I need to hide status bar in some screens and not for all screens